# How to make columns in Custom Tree Panel Resizable?

Tags: extjs, tree

I am using custom tree panel which intern extends Ext.tree.TreePanel. Please find the example in the below link. http://extjs.org.cn/extjs/examples/tree/column-tree.html. I want to make the column resizeable. Even after adding the settings "resizable: true", i am not able to make the column resizable.

Has anyone tried this before making tree panel resizable or any one facing this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code? Without it, it will be hard to check for any issues+prove a response with an example

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to base your attempts off [this implementation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid) rather than the one provided, the example linked to already supports the desired functionality.